# Messaging App. Datastore vs Message Queues

Tags: sockets, socket.io, rabbitmq, google-cloud-datastore

I am creating an offline messaging app. When a user sends a message it is stored in a datastore so if the receiver is offline he can access it when he reconnects. Is this a good approach or is using message queues like RabbitMq or Google Task Queues better?

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to show user a history of the messages, message queues won't give you that. You will need a data store, your approach is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

The message broker will help to communicate asynchronously. It is not a good way to store messages.
You are likely to need somethings to store your messages.

But if it's a need for you app, you could use both.

Comment: Won't sockets allow me to communicate asynchronously anyways? Why are message brokers needed?

Comment: In fact, you can use message broker with sockets : https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html